# Why isn't my content displaying?

Tags: php

How it works: Clicking on the album will take you to "album.php?id=#"

```
//initialize some vars
$albumID = '';

//check what photo we are looking for
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $albumID = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
```

Query:

```
$sql = mysql_query(
SELECT *
FROM albums
JOIN songs
ON albums.performer=songs.performer
WHERE albums.albumID='albumID'
);
```

What I was trying to accomplish is have it display the album and tracklist. Does anybody know how I should fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: well, you didn't mention any problem ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by placing your query in a string:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM albums JOIN songs ON albums.performer=songs.performer";
```

Then, if an album is present, add to that query:

```
if ( !empty( $albumID ) ) {
  $query = $query . " WHERE albums.albumID = $albumID";
}
```

At this point, we can go ahead and run the query:

```
$result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

We run the query, using `mysql_query`, and pass its results into the `$result` variable. If anything goes wrong, like an error in our query, our program will `die`, and the most recent `mysql_error()` will be printed to the screen.

With our `$result` variable, we can now cycle through and print the results:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) {
  echo $row->columnA
}
```

Note that `columnA` is a placeholder, where you should actually write the column name(s) you have stored in your database.

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = mysql_query('
SELECT *
FROM albums
JOIN songs
ON albums.performer=songs.performer
WHERE albums.albumID="'.$albumID.'"');
```

Comment: Does your query start with a single-quote, and end with a double-quote?

Comment: @JonathanSampson oops, forgot it

Answer (score 2):

Also you should be aware that just using `isset()` on a passed variable is ambiguous, you should specificity check and always know what type of value will be passed;

If you want to allow only integers, numbers or a mix of both:

`if(isset($_GET['id']))` Just checks its set this could also be a blank value.

`if(!empty($_GET['id']))` This checks its set and also has a value

`if(!empty($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))` All of the above and is numeric.

The moral of the story is you should never trust user input to be the right type.